# Не открывается изображение openCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Пишу функцию которая открывает все изображения, находящиеся в директории
Однако, при вызове cv2.imread() изображение не считывается, значение переменной остается None

error: (-215:Assertion failed)

```
    images = []
    directory = "C:/Users/Admin/Documents/MEGA/Evgeniy/Study/Диплом/images/"
    folder = os.chdir(directory)
    for file in os.listdir(folder):
        extention = file.split('.')[-1]
        if extention in CORRECT_EXTENTIONS:
            full_path = directory+file
            image = cv2.imread(full_path)
            image = cv2.inRange(image, (0,0,0), (255,255,255))
            images.append(cv2.resize(image, (64,64)))
            cv2.imshow('image', image)
    return images
```

Путь был попробован как через /, так и через \ \

Comment: Для конкатенации путей используйте os.path.join(). Выведите full_path и проверьте, что по этому пути действительно есть картинка.

Comment: Оно не работает даже если поместить код в папку с картинкой и обратиться по имени

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У OpenCV есть проблемы с чтением из файлов содержащими в пути или имени не английские символы. Чтобы прочитать такие файлы вместо `imread()` можно использовать такую конструкцию:

```
image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromfile(full_path, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Ну и полный пример, который работает с русскими именами в пути. И, да, `chdir` тут совершенно не нужен.

```
import os, cv2
import numpy as np

CORRECT_EXTENTIONS = ["png"]
def test():
    images = []
    directory = r".\Русский"
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        extention = file.split('.')[-1]
        if extention in CORRECT_EXTENTIONS:
            full_path = os.path.join(directory, file)
            image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromfile(full_path, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
            image_mask = cv2.inRange(image, (0,0,0), (127,127,127))
            images.append(cv2.resize(image_mask, (64,64)))
            cv2.imshow('image', np.hstack([image, cv2.cvtColor(image_mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)]))
            cv2.waitKey(0)
    return images
    
test()
```