# Opencv Кириллица Python

Tags: python

Есть программа, которая определяет Лицо, когда включается веб камера. Фото находятся в папке KnownFace, если фото на английском языке, то все работает, но если фото будет к примеру Ваня.jpg, то ничего не работает, как понимаю Opencv не понимает кириллицу или подскажите, что нужно сделать.

```
import numpy as np
import face_recognition
import cv2
import os
from PIL import ImageFont, ImageDraw, Image
import FindCloneApi
from datetime import datetime

path = 'KnownFaces'
images = []
classNames = []

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def face_detect():
    myList = os.listdir(path)
    print(myList)

    for cls in myList:
        curImg = cv2.imread(f'{path}/{cls}')
        images.append(curImg)
        classNames.append(os.path.splitext(cls)[0])

    print(classNames)

    def findEncodings(images):
        encodeList = []
        for img in images:
            img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
            encodeList.append(encode)
        return encodeList

    def markAttendance(name):
        with open("Attendance.csv", "r+") as f:
            myDataList = f.readlines()
            nameList = []
            for line in myDataList:
                entry = line.split(',')
                nameList.append(entry[0])
            if name not in nameList:
                now = datetime.now()
                dtString = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                f.writelines(f'\n{name}, {dtString}')

    encodeListKnown = findEncodings(images)
    print("Декодирование закончено")



    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        imgS = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), None, 0.25, 0.25)
        imgS = cv2.cvtColor(imgS, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        facesCurFrame = face_recognition.face_locations(imgS)
        encodeCurFrame = face_recognition.face_encodings(imgS, facesCurFrame)

        for encodeFace, faceLoc in zip(encodeCurFrame, facesCurFrame):
            matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(encodeListKnown, encodeFace)
            faceDis = face_recognition.face_distance(encodeListKnown, encodeFace)
            print(faceDis)
            matchIndex = np.argmin(faceDis)

            name = 'Unknown'

            if matches[matchIndex]:
                name = classNames[matchIndex]
                print(name)
                y1, x2, y2, x1 = faceLoc
                y1, x2, y2, x1 = y1 * 4, x2 * 4, y2 * 4, x1 * 4
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y2 - 35), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)
                cv2.putText(img, name, (x1 + 6, y2 - 6), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)
                markAttendance(name)
            else:
                filename = 'KnownFaces/face.jpg'
                cv2.imwrite(filename, img)
                print("Лицо сохранено")
                #find_clone(filename)



        cv2.imshow("WebCam", img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

def find_clone(img):
    find = FindCloneApi.FindCloneAPI()
    find.login()
    find.upload(img)
    name = 'KnownFaces/' + str(find.out()) + '.jpg'
    os.rename(img, name)
    face_detect()

face_detect()
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не открывается изображение openCV](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1284405/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-opencv)

Comment: Не думаю... тогда была бы ошибка открытия файла.

Comment: Из папки все хорошо читает,  если на английском только имя, если на русском, то ничего не происходит, не могу разобраться

Comment: @ganz В том то и цимес, что `cv2.imread()` молча возвращает `None` для файлов в пути/имени которых есть не английские символы. И никаких ошибок не выскакивает.

Comment: Можно в коде указать, где нужно imdecode и как правильно записать, если не затруднит.  Как понимаю вот эту строчку нужно изменить  curImg = cv2.imread(f'{path}/{cls}')

Comment: По ссылке есть нужная строчка, которую надо написать вместо `imread()` ---> `curImg = cv2.imdecode(np.fromfile(f'{path}/{cls}', dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) `

Comment: Спасибо, теперь читает русские символы! Очень выручили

Comment: Еще вопрос, пока вы тут, какая библиотека нужна, чтобы к примеру, если программа не знает человека, было бы какое-то оповещение, к примеру звук какой-то издавался

Comment: Вот по этому вопросу не подскажу. Увы.

Comment: В любом случае спасибо

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.